# Unable to register SIP account in zoiper (Mac) with elastix server

Tags: macos, sip, elastix

I am trying to create a new SIP account in zoiper and connect it to an elastix server. I have already made the required extension.

Elastix settings:

Elastix server ip address : 192.168.1.2

Extension number : 7003
Display Name : binny
secret : agent01

Zoiper :

IP address : 192.168.1.3

Here are the links to the images:

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QXVH.png
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRcJS.png

Please help me out on this.SIP port is 5060 in zoiper. In Elastix server, I defined the same SIP port.But nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Elastisk is just Asterisk with a web interface. Try to login in Asterisk console in order to see what log messages are send when the soft phone tries to log in. You might need to check carefully if sip.conf and extensions.conf are configured for your soft phone.

Comment: it seems like elastix is not updating the asterisk conf files after i create extensions. This is odd. Any idea about this ?I mean everytime I will have to configure the conf files for my sip clients ?

Comment: You should use a recent enough Elastix provided distribution. If the problem persists, try on Elastix forums.